# PHP and MYSQLI Check if user ID is present and if not create it

Tags: php, forms, session, mysqli

I have been looking for 3 weeks on the Internet for an answer to this question and cannot find anything that even comes close or in handy. I have a Database Table that i need to have checked. If a `Users_ID` is present in that table, I would like my code to display an `update.php` link in my form `action=""` tag and if the `Users_ID` is not present in that db table, then i would like to have an `Insertdb.php` page to be linked in the form instead of an `update.php` page. Here is what I have:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("dbconnect.php");

$users_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE uid=$users_id";
if($results = $con->query($sql)) {
  while($display = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $uid = $display['uid'];
    if($display['uid']==""){
      $pagelink = "insertintodb.php";
    }else{
      $pagelink = "updatedb.php";
    }
  }
  $results->close();
}
?>
```

And my HTML section looks like this:

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $pagelink; ?>" method="POST">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Insert Value" name="something" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" name="submit_data_to_db" />
</form>
```

How would I go about doing this? My current method Posted above is what I'm currently using, however its displaying only `<form action="" method="POST">` when i check it against the pages view-source. Please help me anyway you can. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: had you check the REPLACE statement ?

Comment: Where is come from the $_SESSION['user_id']? If `$pagelink` is empty mean your script do not return results in the query `SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE uid=$users_id`

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto How do I do That?

Comment: Start by adding some error checking. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: _Just checking_ Does the PHP code come before the HTML code in your script file?

Comment: If there're __no records__ selected, `while` __will not__ run.

Comment: Use `num_rows()` instead.

Comment: @RiggsFolly My Php Script is at the top before the html scripts and I am not seeing errors displayed when using the above lines of code

Comment: `if($display['uid']=="")` that condition checks if there is "nothing" in the row. If you have NULL values as defaults, then `NULL` != empty.

Comment: *"however its displaying only <form action="" method="POST">"* - So, it never gets there then, `$pagelink` is empty/no value. Time to see what enable error reporting said, and error handling on the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see you use `$con` but I see nowhere you have declared it.
Can you confirm that actually exists? It is possible your script is halting its execution at that point.

Also a few things I would implement in there:
 1. When you use variables that come from external sources (like your forms), or even other variables really, always care for SQL injection;
2. Your `if & else` can be reduced to just an if (when you find an ID). To all others case, you wish a default behaviour that is your else. So something like this:

```
$pageLink = "insertintodb.php";
if (!empty($display['uid'])) {
    $pageLink = "updatedb.php"
}
```

Comment: I use the `$con` in the `dbconnect.php` file

Comment: Fair enough, and do you have an output for your query? Can you confirm it is executed successfully so your `while` loop is able to execute?

Answer (score 1):

you usually use num_rows method:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("dbconnect.php");

$users_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE uid=$users_id";
if($results = $con->query($sql)) {
  if($results->num_rows() > 0){
      $pagelink = "insertintodb.php";
    }else{
      $pagelink = "updatedb.php";
    }
  }
  $results->close();
}
?>
```